# Repaint not working

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm having a problem with the repaint function.
This is in my jFrame where I pass the word to my jPanel.

```
package Grafisch;
import Logica.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class LingoApp extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

/**
 * Creates new form LingoApp
 */

Letter letter = new Letter();
Woordenlijst woordenlijst = new Woordenlijst();
Lingo lingo = new Lingo();
NewJPanel NewJPanel = new NewJPanel();

public LingoApp() {
    initComponents();
    VolgendeKnop.setEnabled(false);
    ControleerKnop.setEnabled(false);
    GokInput.addActionListener(this);  
}




private void ControleerKnopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    String input = GokInput.getText().replaceAll("\\s","");
    if(input.contains("0123456789") || input.length() <5 || input.length() >5 || input.isEmpty()){
        GokInput.setText("fout");
    }
    else {
        letter.checkLetters(input);
        lingo.vermeerderGok();
        BeurtLabelHoeveelheid.setText(Integer.toString(lingo.geefGokken()));
        ///Here we go
        NewJPanel.setWord(input);
    }
    if(!lingo.checkGokken()){
        AllerleiLabel.setText("Helaas, het woord was: "+ letter.geefWoord()+".");
        ControleerKnop.setEnabled(false);
        VolgendeKnop.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if(lingo.checkWoord(input)){
        AllerleiLabel.setText("Proficiat, het woord was inderdaad "+ letter.geefWoord()+".");
        BeurtLabelHoeveelheid.setText("6");//interface fix
        ScoreLabelHoeveelheid.setText(Integer.toString(lingo.updateScore()));
        lingo.vermeerderBeurt();
        ControleerKnop.setEnabled(false);
        VolgendeKnop.setEnabled(true);
    }
    if(lingo.checkBeurten()){
        if(lingo.checkGoedGeraden()){
            System.out.println("ditmoetnogwordengedaan, 10x goed geraden");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("ditmoetnogwordengedaan, !10x goed geraden");
        }
        VolgendeKnop.setEnabled(false);
        OpgevenKnop.setVisible(true);
        StartSpelKnop.setVisible(true);
    }

}                                              

private void StartSpelKnopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    GokInput.setText("");//fix voor nieuwe ronde
    AllerleiLabel.setText("");//fix voor nieuwe ronde
    OpgevenKnop.setVisible(false);
    StartSpelKnop.setVisible(false);
    woordenlijst.maakLijst();
    String temp = woordenlijst.geefWillekeurigWoord();
    letter.setWoord(temp);
    lingo.setWoord(temp);
    ControleerKnop.setEnabled(true);
    //maakt lijst bij start spel nadat op de knop is gedrukt.De knop zal dan ook verdwijnen.
    //geef woord door aan de andere klasses.
}                                             

private void VolgendeKnopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    ///Add reset code pls
    String temp = woordenlijst.geefWillekeurigWoord();
    letter.setWoord(temp);
    lingo.setWoord(temp);
    ControleerKnop.setEnabled(true);
    VolgendeKnop.setEnabled(false);
    AllerleiLabel.setText("");
    GokInput.setText("");
    lingo.softReset();
}                                            

private void OpgevenKnopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    dispose();
}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LingoApp().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}



// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel AllerleiLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel BeurtLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel BeurtLabelHoeveelheid;
private javax.swing.JButton ControleerKnop;
private javax.swing.JTextField GokInput;
private javax.swing.JLabel GokLabel;
private javax.swing.JButton OpgevenKnop;
private javax.swing.JLabel ScoreLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel ScoreLabelHoeveelheid;
private javax.swing.JButton StartSpelKnop;
private javax.swing.JButton VolgendeKnop;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration                   

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
   ControleerKnop.doClick();
   //eventlistener implementatie
}
}
```

So I'm trying to draw a simple String inside my jpanel.
The method setWord gets the input from my jframe by clicking a button.
Thus inside my jPanel;

```
package Grafisch;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private String word = "example";

/**
 * Creates new form NewJPanel
 */
public void setWord(String input){
    this.word=input;
    repaint();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString(word, 75, 100); // changed the location to make it easier to see
}



public NewJPanel() {
    initComponents();
}
}
```

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Note that I don't think that the code that you've posted shows us the source of your bug, and if you do put in the effort to create and post your minimal example, you'll likely get a decent answer, but without this, likely the question will remain unanswered. Quite possibly you may have two instances of the class that holds the code above, one displayed, and not, and you could be calling `getWord(String input)` on the non-displayed one, but this is just a wild guess. As an aside, consider changing the name of that method since it is not a true "getter" method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I don't think that the code that you've posted shows us the source of your bug, and if you do put in the effort to create and post your minimal example, you'll likely get a decent answer, but without this, likely the question will remain unanswered. Quite possibly you may have two instances of the class that holds the code above, one displayed, and one not displayed, and you could be calling `getWord(String input)` on the non-displayed one, but this is just a wild guess. As an aside, consider changing the name of that method since it is not a true "getter" method but rather is a "setter" method and thus should be renamed `setWord(String word)`.

All anyone can say at this point is that the problem is **not** in the code you've posted. As proof of concept, say I modify your posted code into a working compilable class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ShowWordPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = 250;
   private static final Font WORD_FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 20);
   private String word = "example";

   // Change the name of this method from getXxx to setXxx 
   public void setWord(String input) {
      this.word = input;
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setFont(WORD_FONT); // let's make it big enough to see well
      g.drawString(word, 75, 100); // changed the location to make it easier to see
   }

   @Override // so that the JPanel wil be big enough to show the text
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }
}
```

Then I can use the above class in a GUI creation class, and it works fine:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings({ "serial"})
public class ShowWordPanelTest extends JPanel {
   // create a ShowWordPanel field -- this is to help guarantee
   // that the instance displayed is the same as the one I change 
   // the value of the word field
   private ShowWordPanel showWordPanel = new ShowWordPanel();
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
   private AddWordAction addWordAction = new AddWordAction("Add Word");

   public ShowWordPanelTest() {
      textField.setAction(addWordAction);
      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(textField);
      topPanel.add(new JButton(addWordAction));

      showWordPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Show Word Panel"));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(showWordPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
   }

   private class AddWordAction extends AbstractAction {
      public AddWordAction(String name) {
         super(name);
         int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         String text = textField.getText(); // get text
         showWordPanel.setWord(text); // pass it into the showWordPanel

         // make easy to change text after button press
         textField.selectAll();
         textField.requestFocusInWindow();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ShowWordPanelTest mainPanel = new ShowWordPanelTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShowWordPanelTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: @Jonas: it's still not clear to me as I have no idea why your program did not work. In the future, please try to post a more complete picture of your problem.

Comment: I just noticed you made an @ Override at `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` , but I can't call it there because there is no supertype in my JFrame from where I'm calling it.
It comes from here [img] http://puu.sh/ja8fh/d5224c24ac.png [/img] , a private method in my JFrame when a button is clicked. Edit: I'm sorry but I was trying to make it more clear..

Comment: @Jonas: it's difficult to make sense of your question above without code to back it up. Again, please edit your original question and show pertinent code. Also, please don't post images of code but rather post code and any and all error messages as text only and again as edits to your original question.

Comment: @Jonas: It's still not complete enough. Please see my posted code as an example. It is short, fully compilable and runnable, and you should strive to post the same.

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Jonas: Sorry, but your posted code is neither compilable nor runnable for us.